# why my vue.app doesn't appear in the deploy version?

Tags: javascript, git, vue.js, github

I want to deploy my vue.js project into the Github page.
It works well for HTML, CSS, image, but it didn't render the vue. app components.
The part which shall render the vue. app disappear.
Here is my dis folder structure.
›[image]

And here is my git repo: https://github.com/liulian1004/test.

Appreciate your help. I am a beginner for the Vue.js, and this is my first time to deploy the vue project.
Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: in my dist directory. My website deploys success just not vue.app.

Comment: It looks ok when forked to Codesandbox:  https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-poincare-oynvv

Comment: Interesting....here is the webpage link for github page: https://liulian1004.github.io/test/

Comment: Give a solution to solve this problem. I decide to use code sandbox to deploy this project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're not serving the app from the root directory, but in */test*, you need to configure  `publicPath` in *vue.config.js*:

```js
module.exports = {
   publicPath: '/test/'
}
```

Here is a conditional [`publicPath`](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#publicpath) using *.env*, from the [Vue CLI docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#publicpath) which will allow you to serve it properly in both development and production:

```
module.exports = {
  publicPath: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production'
    ? '/test/'
    : '/'
}
```