# Webpack/Vue not loading runtime.js from root

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vuejs2, vue-router, webpack-dev-server

I am working on a Vue.js project, I work on my local environment and start my development server using `webpack-dev-server --mode development`. Everything works when I go to `localhost:8080/test`, but when I go to `localhost:8080/test/test2` I get 404 errors because it tries to load `runtime.deebb1e0.js` etc from `localhost:8080/test/runtime.deebb1e0.js` instead of `localhost:8080/runtime.deebb1e0.js`. So from the root of the sub directory instead of the root of the website.

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Is `/test` a real directory containing your *index.html* or just a route?

Comment: It's just a route

Comment: See if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65149203/why-my-vue-app-doesnt-appear-in-the-deploy-version/65152559#65152559) works for you.  Use webpack.config.js.  Here are the [docs](https://webpack.js.org/guides/public-path/) for Webpack, it's a little different than Vue CLI